# Yii2: Connect to Oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, yii2, connection

I need to connect a Yii2 model to an Oracle database but it is not working despite reading several answers on this topic.

The Oracle login credentials that I use to manually log in are similar to:

- host: hosturl.abc.com
- port: 1521
- SID: sidname
- user: username
- password: passABC

In the manual login process, I then need to select the appropriate Schema, after which I can see all tables.

I am not clear how to include these details in the oci connection. Here is what I have done without success:

```
'db2' => [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'oci:dbname=//hosturl.abc.com:1521/sidname;charset=UFT-8', 
    'username' => 'username',
    'password' => 'passABC'     
],
```

I get an error "The table does not exist: TableName" however, I get this message even if I supply completely random details ie wrong username, wrong host, wrong password etc)

I am not clear why I cannot connect. Perhaps the Oracle database is rejecting all queries? Do I need to include the SID in the connection credentials?

Any help appreciated

### UPDATE

I think there must be a more general problem with my installation. I am trying a raw connection as follows:

```
$conn = oci_connect("username", "passABC", "//hosturl.abc.com/sidname");
if (!$conn) {
    print "There is a problem";
} else {
    print "Connected to Oracle!";
}
```

This returns the following error:

```
Call to undefined function oci_connect()
```

Any suggestions? This looks like a problem with my php setup??

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Please edit the question and post the errors.

Comment: Question updated. Thanks

Comment: Did you try connecting with pure PHP? I'd try to do that first, and if succeed, then check Yii2 source code of oracle DB driver to see the difference in connection that is made and modify dsn based on that.

Comment: Thanks Milos. I have updated the question following a raw connection test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED!

1) oci_connect not working: SOLVED

Please see this post for more details [How do I connect PHP 7.x to Oracle database on RedHat / CentOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56622628/how-do-i-connect-php-7-x-to-oracle-database-on-redhat-centos). This fix was required for Yii2 to connect to Oracle.

2) Yii2 db credentials for an Oracle database 

/common/config/main-local:

```
   'db' = [
     'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
     'dsn' => 'oci:dbname=//hosturl:1521/SID;charset=UTF8',             
     'username' => 'dbusername',
     'password' => 'dbpassword',
   ]
```

I tried a number of Yii2 oci8 extensions but none of them worked for me. Instead, the fix (1) for the oci_connect worked and no additional Yii2 drivers were required. I was able to use the standard 'yii\db\Connection' class.

3) Database Schema

Within the Oracle database we have a number of schemas and I wasn't sure how to query a specific table within a particular schema. Ultimately the solution was simple: Within each model, prepend the schema name to the table name. For example:

```
class myTable extends ActiveRecord
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'schemaName.myTable';
    }
```